# (Python GUI)Two instructions are ignored when following a hexagon

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When I run the code, [ TKUptake(0,-5,-5) TKUptake(0, 5,-5) ] are ignored when following a hexagon.    What is the problem?

```
import time
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=1000, height=1000, background="black")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(300, 200, 300, 250, 340, 225, fill="yellow")


def TKUptake(x, y, z):
    for i in range(0, 20):
        canvas.move(x, y, z)
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.03)


k = int(input("input value\n"))
for q in range(0, k):
    TKUptake(1, 5, 0)
    TKUptake(1, 5, 5)
    TKUptake(1,-5, 5)
    TKUptake(1,-5, 0)
    TKUptake(0,-5,-5)
    TKUptake(0, 5,-5)
```

Comment: In `canvas.move`, `x` is the item id. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Jay what is item id??  Switching to something else was useless....

Comment: Did you switch it to 1? I think the item id identifies the item on the canvas. In this case 1 would be the polygon. Then the next two arguments tell this item where to move.

Comment: @Jay IT'S AMAZING! I solved it thanks to you. I appreciate your kindness. :)